# Particle System Andengine

Tags: android, andengine

I'm using particle system in my code and having some problem.I simply want to change the color
of particle system to black .I'm confused what should be the value of RGB here or Black or grey Colour.

here is my code

```
   particlesystem.addParticleInitializer(new ColorInitializer(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
   particlesystem.addParticleModifier(new ColorModifier(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
            0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
```

I also attached image for particle system
https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5cYb.png
[image: Particle image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(FYI: Your modifier goes from transparent to opaque.)

You also have to make sure the blend mode is the one you want.

1. [Yet Another Graphical Blending Article](http://www.zeuscmd.com/tutorials/opengles/19-Blending.php)
2. [More Graphical Blending Article](http://www.learnopengles.com/android-lesson-five-an-introduction-to-blending/)
3. [Official Blending Doc](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Blending)

Comment: This guy made AndEngine. That automatically makes his answer *THE* answer. Please accept it, OP. :)